# Controller's length property (5) does not match the number of tabs (10) present in TabBar's tabs property

Tags: flutter, dart

My tabBar's receives values ​​from my model so it must be variable, is there a way to make it variable?

Because the largest number of length ends up being 10, there is an intermediate 8 and the smallest ends up being 5

tabController = TabController(
length: stateView.carts.length,
vsync: this,
initialIndex: 0,
);

Comment: Add some code, so at least someone finds the error.

Comment: O codigo não está errado, só preciso que seja variavél pois a unica parte  necessária eu já inseri ali, pois este erro está ocorrendo por causa da tabController, And you would only need to know if there is already a "variable" tabBar

Answer (score 2):

When you use any TabController then you have to define the TabBarView TabController length is 5 and your TabBarView is length is 3 then it will always getting error, you have to make count same for TabBarView()

tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);

```
TabBar(
              isScrollable: true,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
              labelColor: HColor.indigoColor,
              tabs: [
                Text("Screen1"), 
                Text("Screen2"), 
                Text("Screen3"), 
              ],
              controller: tabController,
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
            ),
```

After define the Tabbarview like this

```
            Expanded(
          child: TabBarView(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            controller: tabController,
            children: [
              Screen1(),
              Screen2(),
              Screen3(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```